# How to upgrade from Nifi registry-0.4.0 to Nifi registry-0.5.0?

Tags: apache-nifi-registry

How to upgrade?and how to migrate flows from last version to new version?i've seen some solution but they were detailed enough!Which step is first?
Thanks!

Without upgrading are necessary,just migrating?

Supplement:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when I need to upgrade my NiFi-Registry, I just replace the `lib` directory with the new version's `lib` directory & `ext/aws`(or any other attached extensions). Then, I look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFIREG/Migration+Guidance) to see if there are additional changes that I need to look for, and apply them as well and then restart the instance.

In your case, you need to do the same and then only take care of the permissions.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much!I also find jar file in ext directory,why don't replace it?

Comment: What jar? All jars of Nifi-Registry, as far as I know are placed in lib dir

Comment: oh, you're right. I'm not using aws myself so I didn't notice it but I'll add it to my answer too.